# css style not loading with sample jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

i am trying to test a sample jquery mobile from demos but it doesn't load css properley 
here is what i am about to test

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css" />
<script src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page Title</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>Page content goes here.</p>
</div><!-- /content -->
<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

i get the text without header and footer design.

Comment: `jquery-1.4.4.min.js` what is this? use `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: i have the scripts loaded localy

Comment: ok, download jquery-1.11.1.min.js and host it locally and make sure all libs are in same level of _page.html_.

Comment: Is the CSS file path correct?

Comment: it's working @Omar , it's something related to jquery library